# how to get null date from kendo date picker in jquery mvc 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-datetimepicker

can i get null date ? if i do not enter any date from datepicker. I want to show date control blank and if user do not enter or select any date then it return null.I am using Kendo Ui.

Comment: Are you binding datepicker control to textbox??

Comment: No.I do not use textbox.

Comment: can you create fiddle for same??

Comment: Yes i create field for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check for value of field to which you have bind the datepicker.

If its empty then return null else return its value as date.